How to hide elevated tabbar in iPadOS 18?
In iOS 18, I've noticed that the tab bar is now positioned at the top of the screen on iPad devices. I'm trying to hide the tab bar programmatically, but setting TabBarController.tabBar.isHidden = true doesn't seem to have any effect. Has anyone else encountered this issue, or does anyone know an alternative method to successfully hide the tab bar in this version of iOS? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
I have tried to update the isTranslucent ,alpha , but they don't have effect on tabbar.

Unfortunately tabBarController.tabBar.isHidden not working in iOS18 ipad. We should use iOS18 api
open func setTabBarHidden(_ hidden: Bool, animated: Bool)
refer this apple forum post  https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/762802

class YourTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        if #available(iOS 18.0, *) {
            traitOverrides.horizontalSizeClass = .compact
        }
    }
}

This code worked for me. Hope it helps!

I have found that this works for me, as well.

If you have an app with 5 or more tabs and want them all to display normally without a more option, don't use .compact, use .unspecified instead.

What about SwiftUI?

iPadOS18 introduces UITabBarController.tabBarHidden for tab bar visibility
if (@available(iOS 18.0, *)) {
    self.tabBarController.tabBarHidden = YES;
}
else {
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
}


After doing a lot of tests, I've had problems with the items visibility, extra bars… That's how I've managed to make it work by making a mix:
final class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        // Workaround to fix the tab bar position in iPad
        if #available(iOS 18.0, *), UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
            tabBar.removeFromSuperview()
            view.addSubview(tabBar)
            traitOverrides.horizontalSizeClass = .compact
        }

    }
}


In my case I just had to point the tabBar and hide it - I hope it helps!
if #available(iOS 18.0, *) {
    myTabBarController.setTabBarHidden(true, animated: false)
} else {
    myTabBarController.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
}

